# Adding new column from aggregated via .loc returns NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I'm having a difficulty to understand why my my code does not work as expected.

I have a datafame structured:
[Screenshot to dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaoTI.png)
(Sorry I don't have high enough reputation to post images)

And I aggregate as follows to get sum of `testBytes`:

```
aggregation = {'testBytes' : ['sum']}
tests_DL_groupped = tests_DL_short.groupby(['measDay','_p_live','_p_compositeId','Latitude','Longitude','testType']).agg(aggregation).reset_index()
```

And now the actual question is **why this code does not work as expected producing `NaN`**:

```
tests_DL_groupped.loc[:,'testMBytes'] = tests_DL_groupped['testBytes']/1000/1000
```

[a not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/St6Cp.png)

while this **works fine**:

```
tests_DL_groupped['testMBytes'] = tests_DL_groupped['testBytes']/1000/1000
```

[a working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6898h.png)

and which should be the preferred pandas way to do it...

Thank You very much!

Comment: Why don't you copy and paste that chunk of data here?

Comment: can you share the index of `tests_DL_groupped`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem `MultiIndex` in columns.

Solution is change:

```
aggregation = {'testBytes' : ['sum']}
```

to:

```
aggregation = {'testBytes' : 'sum'}
```

for avoid it.

Or use [`GroupBy.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
cols = ['measDay','_p_live','_p_compositeId','Latitude','Longitude','testType']
tests_DL_groupped = tests_DL_short.groupby(cols)['testBytes'].sum().reset_index()
```

---

```
tests_DL_groupped = tests_DL_short.groupby(cols, as_index=False)['testBytes'].sum()
```

Comment: Ahh thank You changed `['sum']` to `sum`. 
PS. Which way is preferred?

Comment: @morf - If need only `sum`, second one.

Comment: @morf - `.agg` is obviously use, if need working with mulriple aggregation functions.